# if statement in a hybrid_property expression

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, conditional-statements

I have a `hybrid_property` that performs some conditional and returns a response.  I'd like to be able to query against this field so I've created an `expression`.  However, I'm unsure as to how to write a conditional for this sort of use case.

How do I write an expression that multiplies one of two fields against another based on the result of a conditional?

```
@hybrid_property
def func(self):
    if self.some_column is True:
        return self.true_column * self.amount
    return self.false_column * self.amount

@func.expression
def func(cls):
    # ???
    return
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can use [case](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.case) expression

```
from sqlalchemy import case

@func.expression
def func(cls):
    return case(
        [
            (cls.some_column == True, cls.true_column * cls.amount),
        ],
        else_=cls.false_column * cls.amount
    )
```